# Related SEO and PHP Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, codeigniter-url

I am making a movie database and discussion forum just for my state. I likes to do more SEO work and expecting more traffic.

I likes to do the work in Codeigniter framework .

My doubt is how codeigniter will help in SEO process or there is any disadvantages if I used CI ? or any other PHP framework will help in SEO process more than CI

Please help

Thanks

Comment: I think that you're confusing terminologies!
CI = framework
SEO = search engine optimization, meaning, promoting your website in many different ways (back-links, anchored text, paid ads etc)
There is no connection between the two.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: CI is more in the domain of the back-end, whereas SEO is more in the domain of the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There basically is no 'disadvantage' when using codeigniter. I think you mean stuff like Seo friendly url's.

Codeigniter offers those ability. Default url scheme is like:

http://www.Yoururl.com/index.php/controller_name/controller_function/

You can get rid of the index.php in the url by modifying ci's config and use .htaccess.

See [Codeigniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for that.

Thats the only point, ci supports you - rest is up to you!